# What is "DocumentType" in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was going through some code and I found that one of the class property is having type as 'DocumenType'. Hovering over that I can see that it is an interface. I was wondering what is use of 'DocumenType' as don't find much details over internet.

Comment: If you see the line `interface DocumentType {`, this is a custom interface and is specific to your codebase

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentType

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentType

> The **`DocumentType`** interface represents a `Node` containing a doctype.

To put it simply, it is effectively the root node of the entire HTML document as far as JavaScript is concerned.

Can not say more than that without seeing the actual code.